# Why prestashop 1.7 based site is slow?

Tags: performance, server, pagespeed, prestashop-1.7, yslow

I am not good in the prestashop backend(but can change front end as I want), and I wanted to know that why my prestashop 1.7 based site(i.e., [laptopandmobile.co.in](https://laptopandmobile.co.in)) is slow?

I check it on gtmetrix, and I'm getting good score in pagespeed, but still the load time shows greater than 10seconds. Can anyone help what is the issue?

Comment: This is usually something you should talk about with your hoster.
We can not help you if you don't share your server info with us, but check [this](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/) guide to see what server requirements you need.

Comment: Make sure Smarty cache enabled on _Advanced Parameters > Performance_ tab and Compilation doesn't set to _Force compilation_